# Ruby on Rails Capistrano Update release

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano

I'm confused about what to do to get Capistrano to update.

I've committed my changes to git. Well hell I'll write all the steps I took.

1. git commit -a
2. git push
   (all files successfully pushed to the remote git repository. all changes noted)
3. cap deploy

But it doesn't deploy the latest version of the site.

In fact it deploys the oldest version.

**Cap Deploy Response**

```
triggering load callbacks


* 2013-07-13 17:09:08 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-07-13 17:09:08 executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://ubuntu@54.229.78.34/~/liquid_admin.git master"
    command finished in 3150ms
  * executing "git clone -b master --depth 1 ssh://ubuntu@54.229.78.34/~/liquid_admin.git /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911 && cd /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911 && git checkout -b deploy d609108bf81df3cb558f7536c3cee98d852b4ec5 && git submodule init && git submodule sync && export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE && rm -Rf /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/.git && (echo d609108bf81df3cb558f7536c3cee98d852b4ec5 > /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/REVISION)"
    servers: ["54.229.78.34"]
    [54.229.78.34] executing command
 ** [54.229.78.34 :: out] Cloning into '/home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911'...
 ** [54.229.78.34 :: out] remote: Counting objects: 276, done.
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (3/239)   
 ** [54.229.78.34 :: out] remote: Compressing objects:   2% (5/239)   
 ** [54.229.78.34 :: out] remote: Compressing objects:   3% (8/239)   
 ** [54.229.78.34 :: out] remote: Compressing objects:   4% (10/239)   
 ** [54.229.78.34 :: out] remote: Compressing objects:   5% (12/239)   
 ** [54.229.78.34 :: out] remote: Compressing objects:   6% (15/239)
```

(then a hell of a lot more of those then...)

```
** [54.229.78.34 :: out] Resolving deltas: 100% (58/58), done.
 ** [54.229.78.34 :: out] Switched to a new branch 'deploy'
    command finished in 5206ms
  * 2013-07-13 17:09:19 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2013-07-13 17:09:19 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911 && bundle install --gemfile /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/Gemfile --path /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["54.229.78.34"]
    [54.229.78.34] executing command
    command finished in 2138ms
  * executing "chmod -R -- g+w /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911 && rm -rf -- /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/system && mkdir -p -- /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/ && ln -s -- /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/shared/system /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/system && rm -rf -- /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/log && ln -s -- /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/shared/log /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/log && rm -rf -- /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/tmp/ && ln -s -- /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/shared/pids /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["54.229.78.34"]
    [54.229.78.34] executing command
    command finished in 756ms
  * executing "find /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/images /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/stylesheets /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201307131509.22 -- {} ';'; true"
    servers: ["54.229.78.34"]
    [54.229.78.34] executing command
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] find:
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] `/home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/images'
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] : No such file or directory
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] 
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] find:
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] `/home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/stylesheets'
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] : No such file or directory
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] 
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] find:
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] `/home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911/public/javascripts'
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] : No such file or directory
 ** [out :: 54.229.78.34] 
    command finished in 767ms
  * 2013-07-13 17:09:23 executing `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' rm -f /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/current && sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ln -s /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/releases/20130713150911 /home/ubuntu/liquid_admin/current"
    servers: ["54.229.78.34"]
    [54.229.78.34] executing command
    command finished in 837ms
 ** transaction: commit
```

**UPDATE**

I did "cap deploy:update" and it updated *some* of the files.  For example my database.yml was updated.  But none of the new views, new controllers, or new models are there...

**UPDATE 2**

It seems to have only changed files that existed during my first deployment. So "posts" and "home" and all that is changed... but any new controllers, models, or views that I made after that were not deployed.

Comment: Could you paste Capistrano output? also git log in your remote and local?

Comment: Without more detail, this is a bit of a guess, but if you've got multiple branches in git you should make sure that capistrano is deploying from the correct one. That's done with the `set :branch, 'branch_name'` line.

Comment: Pasted the cap output. Where can I find the git log? On the local or remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cap deploy is generally deploying the master.. Did you make changes in a different branch and forgot about merging it back?

Comment: I suppose I made changes on the live server and didn't do any merging... I just figured it created a new release anyway... But on my local machine I always made all the changes in the same folders as the original. Could it be that I just shouldn't be making changes on the live server then? Only make them on the local and then deploy?

Comment: thats right... this could be the problem.. IF you go on the server, save your changes to your local copy, then type git reset --hard on the server and deploy again with the updated local version, then everything should be right...

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "save your changes to your local copy"? Do you mean physically back up my local copy and then copy the files back after the git reset and then deploy again?

Comment: First I did a "git reset --hard" on the local server (since the remote server is just a bare repository.)

Then I did a "git commit -a" which told me there were no changes but that there were untracked files.

So I did a "git add ." to add all the files that weren't being tracked.

Finally I ran "git commit -a" again and "git push".  

This updated my repository with all the new files and then "cap deploy" functioned as expected.